# Update transform in SVG using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to update transform of an object using jQuery, Normal divs are updating but SVG is not updating. Here is my code:

**SVG:**

```
<svg>
    <polygon id="poly" transform="rotate(0 180 180)">
</svg>
```

**HTML Div:**

```
<div id="speed-number">0</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$.getJSON("file.json", function(result){
    var realtime = result.realtime;
    var rt_angle = realtime/1200*100;
    var needle = rt_angle/100*270;
    $("#poly").css("transform", "rotate("+needle+" 180 180)");
    $('#speed-number').text(realtime);
});
```

HTML Div is getting updated successfully but SVG polygon is not getting updated. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That's a transform attribute not a transform CSS you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<polygon>` has a `transform` attribute. But you are calling jQuery's `css()` function, which sets the `style` attribute.

You need to either:

1. Call a function that changes the attribute. Eg. `attr()`

```js
var realtime = 600;
var rt_angle = realtime/1200*100;
var needle = rt_angle/100*270;
$("#poly").attr("transform", "rotate("+needle+" 180 180)");
$('#speed-number').text(realtime);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="360" height="200">
    <polygon id="poly" points="180,175, 180,185, 10,180" transform="rotate(0 180 180)"/>
</svg>

<div id="speed-number">0</div>
```

2. Or you can keep using `css()`, but you'll need to make some changes:

   - You need to add units to your CSS values, since units are required in CSS.
   - The three parameter version of `rotate()` is not supported in the CSS version of `transform`.  You'll need to use `transform-origin` to specify the centre of rotation.

```js
var realtime = 600;
var rt_angle = realtime/1200*100;
var needle = rt_angle/100*270;
$("#poly").css({"transform": "rotate("+needle+"deg)",
                "transform-origin": "180px 180px"});
$('#speed-number').text(realtime);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="360" height="200">
    <polygon id="poly" points="180,175, 180,185, 10,180" transform="rotate(0 180 180)"/>
</svg>

<div id="speed-number">0</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but  i have created a div outside of svg and used .css, deleted the polygon object.